# Link event listener returning child element

Tags: javascript

I am probably missing something obvious with this. I recently transferred to using Vanila JS form Jquery and one thing I can't crack is..

When I add an eventListener to a link that contains child elements, the event returns the child element not the link element itself.

I have tried a lot of different solutions, and can stop this adding pointer-events:none on child elements, however I need a different solution.

Your help would be appreciated

```
<a href="#" id="click-me" id="2">
<span class="child-span"></span>
</a>

let test  = document.getElementById('click-me')

test.addEventListener('click',function(el){
el.preventDefault()
console.log(el.target)
})
```

This returns the span element, however I am trying to return the #click-me id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Event-Listener for click events passes not the element as argument. It passes an `event`-object as its argument. Inside that event-object is the element that fired the event under the `target`-property. If you want the element that the event was bound to, you can use the `currentTarget`-property.

```js
let testElement = document.getElementById('click-me')
testElement.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Someone clicked the element!');
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
});
```

```css
#click-me {
  background-color: #cff;
}

#click-me .child-span {
  background-color: #f99;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="click-me" id="2">
  <span class="child-span">CLICK ME!</span>
  <span class="child-span">No, please click me!</span>
  ... or maybe me?
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am trying to return the id for the #click-me element, how would I do this form your example ?

Comment: event.target will return the element on which the click happen. In this case it will return the span and not anchor.

Comment: Please try the example in my answer again. I updated the post just a moment ago and it should show you the differences and how to achieve your goal.

Comment: Please check the answer I have already added with correct o/p

Answer (score 1):

use the below JS. It will work.

```
let test  = document.getElementById('click-me')

test.addEventListener('click',function(el){
el.preventDefault()
console.log(el.currentTarget)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not attaching the event on the anchor element. The passed `el` refers to the current *event* not the element, you can refer `this` object to target the element on which the event is generating:

Please Note: You can use `Event.stopPropagation()` to prevent further propagation in bubbling phases.

```js
let test  = document.getElementById('click-me')

test.addEventListener('click', function(el){
  //el.stopPropagation();
  console.log(this.id);
})
```

```html
<a href="#" id="click-me">Link
  <br><span class="child-span">Element</span>
</a>
```